# Compare alphanumeric strings in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have a core data attribute titled 'gLotNumber' which stores alphanumeric strings. Examples include `P1`, `P5`, `7`, `P10` and `11`.

I need to provide a way to search this attribute to the user. The way I can think of providing this is by using NSPredicate on core data using:

```
[fetchRequest1 setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(gLotNumber >= 'P1') AND (gLotNumber <= 'P15')"]];
```

This should result in all entries which start with `P` and range between 1 to 15. The above code doesn't produce accurate results at all.

Do you know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work

I don't have a coredata setup hence harcoded some array values.

```
    NSArray *array = @[@{@"gLotNumber":@"P1"},@{@"gLotNumber":@"P15"},@{@"gLotNumber":@"P13"},@{@"gLotNumber":@"P0"},@{@"gLotNumber":@"11"},@{@"gLotNumber":@"10"},@{@"gLotNumber":@"P31"},@{@"gLotNumber":@"P013"},@{@"gLotNumber":@"16"},@{@"gLotNumber":@"P38"}];
    NSArray *filtered = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.gLotNumber BEGINSWITH 'P' AND SELF.gLotNumber <= 'P15'"]];
    NSSortDescriptor *desc = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"gLotNumber" ascending:YES comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1,id obj2){
        return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
    }];
    NSArray *sorted = [filtered sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[desc]];
```

You can set the sort descriptor and predicate to the `fetch request` Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah this may work but I need it to be dynamic, i.e., the user may not necessarily search for anything with "P". It can be anything. Like search between 1 and 10, P5 and P15, A3 and A9, etc.

Comment: you need to take the input from the user and then form the predicate accordingly. It depends on ur req.. If the user types 11 then P11 should be shown or should not be shown etc. or anything that begins with 11 like 111,113,110 should be shown. also the limit that your applying to the searchs